# Loop through Range Areas

Tags: excel, office-js

In Excel, make a multi-selection, ie: `A1:A3` and `D1:F4`.

In VBA, I can easily loop through Range's Areas using:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
        Debug.Print Selection.Areas(i).Address
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is a very important Range property. How can I accomplish this in Excel Javascript API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available right now; but it is something we are looking into adding support for in the coming months. No timeline available yet.